# Add Column in "Add Stock Item" dialog box in Sales Order screen of Acumatica

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

How can I add the "ItemType" column from "Stock Items" screen to "Add Stock Item" dialog box of Sales Order screen.

[Stock Item Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7aV5j.png)

[Sales Order Dialog Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VgAfT.png)

Is there any direct method using the Acumatica Customization Editor we can do this work or I need to use programming or coding to accomplish the task

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be creating cache extension for the **BQL** table `SOSiteStatusSelected` and add a new field `UsrItemType` like following:

```
public class SOOrderEntryExt : PXGraphExtension<SOOrderEntry>
{
public sealed class SOSiteStatusSelectedExt : PXCacheExtension<SOSiteStatusSelected>
{
    [PXDBString(1, IsFixed = true, BqlField = typeof(InventoryItem.itemType))]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Item Type", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible)]
    [INItemTypes.ListAttribute]
    public string UsrItemType { get; set; }
    public abstract class usrItemType : BqlType<IBqlString, string>.Field<usrItemType> { }
}
}
```

After this add the `UsrItemType` field on the `Inventory Lookup` screen in the **Sales Orders** form from the **Customization Project Editor** menu.
[image]